# How to load formatted HTML into ckeditor 5, not markup with tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

So I would like to load already formatted html into ckeditor 5.  Since ultimately the data will be coming from this control, I'm not too worried about the format being bad, but to test I have just been using a bolded section and a break.  When loading into the editor, I would expect something like this:

This **is a test**

Another **test**

But am actually getting:

```
This <b> is a test <br/>Another test
```

This is of course identical to the source and is not being marked up.

I have tried a handful of things, including the setData call and the following code, which was modified from the ckeditor examples:

```
const viewFragment = theEditor.data.processor.toView('@Model.MailTemplate.MailTemplateData');
const modelFragment = theEditor.data.toModel(viewFragment);

theEditor.model.insertContent(modelFragment, theEditor.model.document.selection);
```

I also tried to simply add the markup to the div.  All of these display the raw html, not the formatted text I would like.

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Complete (relevant) code:

```
            <div class="document-editor">
                <div class="document-editor__toolbar"></div>
                <div class="document-editor__editable-container">
                    <div class="document-editor__editable">
                        @* @Model.MailTemplate.MailTemplateData *@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

// In script block...
        DecoupledEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('.document-editor__editable'))
            .then(editor => {
                const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('.document-editor__toolbar');
                toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);

                theEditor = editor;
                //window.editor = editor;

                const viewFragment = theEditor.data.processor.toView('@Model.MailTemplate.MailTemplateData');
                const modelFragment = theEditor.data.toModel(viewFragment);

                theEditor.model.insertContent(modelFragment, theEditor.model.document.selection);

                //theEditor.setData('@Model.MailTemplate.MailTemplateData');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
```

Note that the text in the document-editor__editable is commented out, but I tried this as well.

Comment: Try posting your actual code that you are using.

Comment: @imvain2, added all related code.

Comment: Using your code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bmedj6as/, it is working. The only thing I did was get rid of some of the code that I didn't see in the ckeditor example for testing purposes.

Comment: This works, it was just not being properly loaded from ASP.Net.  At least I know ckEditor is doing what it needs to.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem might be with ASP.net and including the CDN javascript. Try stripping your page down to the bare minimum using asp.net and verifying CKEDITOR works, then adding from there.